# Microsoft Dynamics 2011 - Automate quote process (produce quote, attach to email all in one go)

Tags: crm, microsoft-dynamics

I am working on a Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 development.  I have most of the basics mastered, however could do with some feedback/suggestions on handling the quotation side of things.

I have produced a custom quote report to ensure that its got our organisations branding and product detail formatted correctly, however at current the process to email a quote would be;

1. Create opportunity and convert products to a quote.
2. Run the quote report (as a PDF).
3. Attach the PDF to an email.
4. Input the customers email address to the email and set the regarding as the opportunity.

Ideally I would prefer if on producing the quote it could attach it to an email with the customers email address and regarding set as the opportunity.

Any suggestions on how I would do this, or at least portions of it?

Answer (score 1):

The long and short of it is unfortunately not all of this is possible without some coding to help it along. The problem you're going to hit is the automatic report generation. What you're looking at here is a workflow with some custom workflow activity (c# code) to help it along. I haven't ever needed to do this, but this is an idea of what you need to do:

1. Create a new Workflow Process based on a Quote
2. Set it as an on demand process
3. The Workflow will create a new email based on the quote details
4. Launch and attach the report to the email and send it

Point 4 needs to execute as a custom workflow activity (some C# code) that knows what report to run (or is told what report to run) and how to attach it to the email. And it then can send the email for you.

Now, that's all fine if you're working with CRM on-premise, but I have as of yet to see if custom workflow activities are support in CrmOnline. If not you'll need to use a custom entity and some plugins to work around this instead.

So, it's possible, but not without some development to help it along. You need to take a look at workflows to see how much they can help you though.